# don't allow to input type to select expired date

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have input type date like below.
I can't select current date in above example. Please help.
Check the snippet added

```js
function CheckD()
{
    var current=new Date(document.getElementById('task_date').value);
    var today=new Date();
    if(current.getTime() <= today.getTime())
    {
        alert("You Can't Assign Task For Expired Date");
        document.getElementById('task_date').value="";
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="task_date" name="task_date" class="form-control" onchange="return CheckD();">
```

Comment: You should have to once visit this before asking http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using getTime(), use getDate()

```js
function CheckD()
{
    var current=new Date(document.getElementById('task_date').value);
    var today=new Date();
    if(current.getDate() < today.getDate())
    {
        alert("You Can't Assign Task For Expired Date");
        document.getElementById('task_date').value="";
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="task_date" name="task_date" class="form-control" onchange="return CheckD();">
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are using `getTime` which will change after every second, so `getDate` will be appropriate in this case

```js
function CheckD() {
  var current = new Date(document.getElementById('task_date').value);
  var today = new Date();
  if (current.getDate() < today.getDate()) {
    alert("You Can't Assign Task For Expired Date");
    document.getElementById('task_date').value = "";
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="task_date" name="task_date" class="form-control" onchange="return CheckD();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use `getDate()` as pointed out by Akhil & brk,

But for some reason if you must use `getTime()`, change your function to:

```js
function CheckD()
{
    var current=new Date(document.getElementById('task_date').value);
    var today=new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);// <-- this will effectively change time component to 00:00:00 
    if(current.getTime() < today.getTime())
    {
        alert("You Can't Assign Task For Expired Date");
        document.getElementById('task_date').value="";
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="task_date" name="task_date" class="form-control" onchange="return CheckD();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
if(current.getTime() <= today.getTime())
```

to this

```
if(current.getDate() < today.getDate() )
```